# Enabling macro by default on a workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am new to VBA/Excel programming, I am refreshing a pivot table using a macro. I have the following VBA code on one of my sheets.

**Excel version : 2013 ( saving my file as macro enabled workbook)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
RefreshPivotTables
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
RefreshPivotTables
End Sub
```

The code works fine when I switch back and forth after enabling the macro, but when I open the Excel doc I get this "Enable macro ribbon" at the top which is preventing the macro from running. I need to switch to another tab and come back to my original sheet to activate the macro.

Is there a way to set "Enable Macro" for the workbook by default / some code that will do this on behalf of the running user? I cannot expect all my users to switch workbooks and come back to see the refresh happen.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the options in Excel and then to the trust center settings. Put the location in as a trusted location.

Alternatively on my machine if I open a sheet, enable macros then close it again a few times Excel asks if I want to make this a trusted document.